# why this C++ program gives incorrect output?

Tags: c++, hex, iostream, numeric, octal

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<std::ios::showbase<<123<<", "<<std::hex<<123<<", "<<std::oct<<123<<'\n';
}
```

Expected Output: 123, 0x7b, 0173

Acquired Output: 512123, 7b, 173 (see live demo here: http://ideone.com/Khzj5j )

But If I modify the above program slightly as following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<showbase<<123<<", "<<hex<<123<<", "<<oct<<123<<'\n';
}
```

Now I got desired output. (see live demo here http://ideone.com/gcuHbm ).

Why first program gave incorrect output but 2nd program doesn't? What's going wrong in first program?

Comment: The first program you are using std::ios::showbase, the second one you are using std::showbase.

Comment: If you want to use i/o manipulation features, you should include the <iomanip> header.

Comment: @Downvoters: specify reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::ios::showbase` is a format flag.  `std::showbase` is a function that takes a `std::ios_base` and calls `ios_base::setf(std::ios::showbase)` on it to set the `showbase` flag.

You use the prior in your first example and the latter in your second example.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<std::ios::showbase<<123<<", "<<std::hex<<123<<", "<<std::oct<<123<<'\n';
}
```

This uses `std::ios::showbase` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/)

While your other program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<showbase<<123<<", "<<hex<<123<<", "<<oct<<123<<'\n';
}
```

Uses `std::showbase` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase) which is why you're getting different results.

Changing the first program to use `std::showbase` gives you your expected output:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<std::showbase<<123<<", "<<std::hex<<123<<", "<<std::oct<<123<<'\n';
}
```

http://ideone.com/OodBvo

Comment: What is the difference in the links you provided? Both lead to `std::showbase`...

Answer (score 2):

[`std::ios::showbase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) is a format flag that has some implementation defined value.  When you call `std::cout << std::ios::showbase` you are displaying that value and not setting the stream format flag.

In you second example you are using [`std::showbase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase) which sets the format flag of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

In `std::ios_base`, `showbase` is a `fmtflag` that has an implementation-defined value. In this case, it appears to be `512`. On the other hand, there is a stream manipulator (aka, a function) also called `showbase`, which calls `setf(std::ios_base::showbase)`. This is defined as a free function in `namespace std` whereas the `fmtflag` is a member of `std::ios_base`.